# How to correctly write the index as a primary key when exporting a GeoDataFrame to PostGIS

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geopandas, psycopg2, geoalchemy-2

I'm trying to write a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/geodataframe.html) containing some `POLYGON Z` features directly to a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) table which already has the right structure, especially a `PolygonZ` geometry column. This works fine:

```python
G.to_postgis('test', engine, if_exists='append')
```

In a first attempt, `psycopgg2` had trouble finding the SRID:

```python
InternalError: (psycopg2.errors.RaiseException) find_srid() - could not find the    
corresponding SRID - is the geometry registered in the GEOMETRY_COLUMNS table?    
Is there an uppercase/lowercase mismatch?    
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function find_srid(character varying,character varying,    
character varying) line 17 at RAISE

[SQL: SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'test', 'geometry');]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/2j85)
```

This was because the name of my the geometry field in my GeoDataFrame didn't match the one in PostGIS!
They *have* to match.

The `test` table SQL code looks like this in [pgAdmin](https://www.pgadmin.org/):

```sql
-- Table: public.test

-- DROP TABLE public.test;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test
(
    id integer NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( 
        INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 2147483647 CACHE 1 
    ),
    geometry geometry(PolygonZ,2056)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.test
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Now, if I write to a table which doesn't already exist, GeoPandas will create it:

```python
G.to_postgis('test2', engine, if_exists='replace') #table 'test2' doesn't already exist
```

That's cool, but then, the SQL code associated to this table looks like:

```sql
-- Table: public.test2

-- DROP TABLE public.test2;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test2
(
    geometry geometry(PolygonZ,2056)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.test2
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: idx_test2_geometry

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_test2_geometry;

CREATE INDEX idx_test2_geometry
    ON public.test2 USING gist
    (geometry)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

There is no `id` column (which I expected as the [primary key constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-PRIMARY-KEYS)). It could have simply be taken from the GeoDataFrame index if such index also meet the two conditions of a [RDB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database) primary key: it is unique and it cannot be null.

This seems actually possible using the `index` option:

```python
G.to_postgis('test2', engine, if_exists='replace', index=True)
```

which leads to:

```sql
-- Table: public.test2

-- DROP TABLE public.test2;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.test2
(
    index bigint,
    geometry geometry(PolygonZ,2056)
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.test2
    OWNER to postgres;
-- Index: idx_test2_geometry

-- DROP INDEX public.idx_test2_geometry;

CREATE INDEX idx_test2_geometry
    ON public.test2 USING gist
    (geometry)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
-- Index: ix_public_test2_index

-- DROP INDEX public.ix_public_test2_index;

CREATE INDEX ix_public_test2_index
    ON public.test2 USING btree
    (index ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

but as the `index` option is a boolean which default value is `True`, I would have expected the exact same behavior by specifying `index=True` or not.
Indeed, the `index` column is created only when this option is manually specified.
If it's not, there is only the `geometry` column (no `index`).

But even when the `index` field is present, it does not appear to be a primary key as when the table was created manually.

Hence my question: is it possible to create a new table with a primary key corresponding to the index of the GeoDataFrame when using [`GeoDataFrame.to_postgis()`](https://geopandas.org/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis.html#geopandas.GeoDataFrame.to_postgis) method? I cannot figure it out on the documentation.

Versioning:

OS:          Ubuntu 18.04
Python:      3.6.9

```
geopandas:   0.9.0
psycopg2:    2.9.1 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)
sqlalchemy:  1.3.13
geoalchemy2: 0.9.2
```

PostgreSQL: `13.3 (Debian 13.3-1.pgdg100+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`

PostGIS full version:

```
POSTGIS="3.1.2 cbe925d" [EXTENSION]
 PGSQL="130"
 GEOS="3.7.1-CAPI-1.11.1 27a5e771"
 PROJ="Rel. 5.2.0, September 15th, 2018"
 LIBXML="2.9.4"
 LIBJSON="0.12.1"
 LIBPROTOBUF="1.3.1"
 WAGYU="0.5.0 (Internal)" TOPOLOGY
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't figure this problem out by reading the documentation. In fact, I don't think there is a solution to this problem. `GeoDataFrame.to_postgis()` converts the `GeoDataFrame` to a regular pandas `DataFrame` and then calls [`DataFrame.to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html). The `to_sql` method doesn't seem to support creation of primary keys (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30867390/python-pandas-to-sql-how-to-create-a-table-with-a-primary-key) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469391/dataframe-to-sql-index-as-primary-key-in-postgresql)). And there also doesn't seem to be much activity on the related [github issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/7984#issuecomment-675542837).

I took the manual creation of a primary key with an `alter table .. add primary key ..` statement as a last resort.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but I seem to be bumping into something similar in the `could not find the corresponding SRID` error. The SQL in the error `SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'Peng', 'geometry');` is looking for a table that doesn't exist. In my database is a 'geom' column. Running the same query in PGADMIN finds the SRID without any issues.